# Create table merging two tables setting default values if value is not present using WHERE clause

Tags: sqlite

I want to create a temporary table containing location score for some words in some pages.

In sqlite I have 2 tables, pages and wordlocations:

```
pages
-------
|url|
|example.com|
|example2.com|
|example3.com|
```

and:

```
wordlocations
-------
|    url     |wordid|location|
|example.com |     1|       2|
|example.com |     1|      35|
|example.com2|     1|       0|
|example.com2|     1|      75|
|example.com3|     2|      75|
```

And I want to create a table that contains the url, the lowest location score, and if word is not present => set the location score to 10000. So in the example below, when I want to create a table for the `wordid = 1`, I want it to look something like:

```
result
-------
|    url     |min(location)|
|example.com |            2|
|example2.com|            0|
|example3.com|       100000|
```

I tried with 

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result AS SELECT url, IFNULL(MIN(location), 100000) FROM wordlocation WHERE wordid = 1 GROUP BY url;`

But that left out the pages where the wordid weren't present, i.e.

```
result
-------
|    url     |min(location)|
|example.com |            2|
|example2.com|            0|
```

How would I go about to retrieve such a table that contains all the pages with it's lowest location score, and still keep the pages that doesn't contain the wordids with a default value?

Comment: How is the pages table relevant? Is it?

Comment: @Shawn it's a simplified version, the real table contains other values as well, but sure, I guess you could skip it for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this which uses `UNION` to merge the 2 cases:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result AS  
    SELECT url, MIN(location) AS minlocation
    FROM wordlocations 
    WHERE wordid = 1
    GROUP BY url
    UNION
    SELECT url, 100000 AS minlocation
    FROM wordlocations 
    WHERE wordid <> 1
    GROUP BY url;
```

**Edit**, 2nd version:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result AS  
    SELECT url, MIN(location) AS minlocation
    FROM wordlocations 
    WHERE wordid = 1
    GROUP BY url
    UNION
    SELECT url, 100000 AS minlocation
    FROM wordlocations 
    WHERE url NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT url FROM wordlocations WHERE wordid = 1)
    GROUP BY url;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185088/discussion-on-answer-by-forpas-create-table-merging-two-tables-setting-default-v).